# Java windowbuilder multiple audiofiles in one window

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, windowbuilder

I have a question about my code, first of all little pre information about what it is going...

A Graphic Design friend of mine, has an exhibition/project from her University to influence the ppl with acoustic drugs (the topic of the exhibition is drugs..)

She wanted to have an interface, where a user can push a button and listen to an acoustic drug. further the user should have the opportunity, to mix up the sounds like kokain and heroin and stop either all by repushing the buttons each or just one button for stopping one title.

My code has follow problems. at the time i debug the code, my second listen button is not shown, u have to push the left bot of the window that the button is visible, and u can start one title and stop it, but if u play two sounds in same time, u can stop one, if u stop the second one its shown that its stopped but its actually not.

I would be happy if somebody could help me in my case.

Here the code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class c extends JFrame {

  String lsd="/Users/shaggy/Desktop/Lsd.wav";  
  JButton btnPlaySoundLSD=new JButton("Listen");
  Clip clip = null;

  String koka ="/Users/shaggy/Desktop/Kokain.wav";
  JButton btnPlaySoundKokain=new JButton("Listen");


public c(){
  btnPlaySoundLSD.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 240);

  btnPlaySoundLSD.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
              JButton b=(JButton)arg0.getSource();
              // play the sound clip
              if(b.getText().equals("Listen")){
                b.setText("Stop");
                btnPlaySoundCLickLSD();
              } else if(btnPlaySoundLSD.getText().equals("Stop")) {
                  b.setText("Listen");
                  clip.stop();
              }
            } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                    | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
});

  setSize(500, 500);
  getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  getContentPane().add(btnPlaySoundLSD);
  setVisible(true);


    btnPlaySoundKokain.setBounds(0, 238, 250, 240);

    btnPlaySoundKokain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg1) {
                try {
                  JButton b=(JButton)arg1.getSource();
                  // play the sound clip
                  if(b.getText().equals("Listen")){
                    b.setText("Stop");
                    btnPlaySoundCLickKokain();
                  }     else if(btnPlaySoundKokain.getText().equals("Stop")) {
                  b.setText("Listen");
                  clip.stop();
              }
            } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                    | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

  setSize(500, 500);
  getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  getContentPane().add(btnPlaySoundKokain);
  setVisible(true);
}


private void btnPlaySoundCLickKokain() throws     LineUnavailableException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException{ 

  File soundFile = new File(koka);
  AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

  DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
  clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
  clip.open(sound);

  clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
  public void update(LineEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
    System.out.println("stop");
      event.getLine().close();
    }
  }
  });

  clip.start();

}


private void btnPlaySoundCLickLSD() throws LineUnavailableException,     IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException{ 

  File soundFile = new File(lsd);
  AudioInputStream sound =     AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

  DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,     sound.getFormat());
  clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
  clip.open(sound);

  clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
  public void update(LineEvent event) {
    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
    System.out.println("stop");
      event.getLine().close();
    }
  }
  });

  clip.start();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    c cc=new c();
}

}
```